# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'ms' must be a double

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'

driver_path = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe'
serv = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv, options=opts)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/SpiderCode/selenuim_webdirver/demo.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
  File "E:\pythonProject\test_frame\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1142, in implicitly_wait
    self.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
  File "E:\pythonProject\test_frame\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\pythonProject\test_frame\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'ms' must be a double
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using *`chrome=95.0.4638.69`* you need to [download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and use the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) of [chromedriver=95.0.4638.69](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/notes.txt)

Comment: what do you exactly mean by _The old version is still in progress_?

Comment: You are right, the driver replacement failed, so error

Comment: stop old driver process and replace new driver successfully